# How to combine input parser with fullRunInputTask?

Tags: scala, sbt

In my build.sbt I want to have a task with input parameters that calls a `main` method in my code, but I'd like to have the parameters **parsed** before calling the method.

This is the InputKey definition:

```
val clearDatabase = inputKey[Unit]("Clear database, arguments:  endpoint user password")
```

A parser I'd like to use:

```
val databaseTaskParser = sbt.Def.spaceDelimited("endpoint username password").map(_.toList).map {
  case List(endpoint) => (endpoint, "", "")
  case List(endpoint, username, password) => (endpoint, username, password)
  case _ =>
    sys.error("Supported arguments: \"endpoint\" or \"endpoint username password\"")
}
```

And then I know that to pass input arguments to the main method I need to use `fullRunInputTask` parametrized with the InputKey defined above:

```
fullRunInputTask(clearDatabase, Compile, "my.code.ClearDatabaseTask")
```

Now, how can I combine the call to `fullRunInputTask` with using the `databaseTaskParser` (to display error when a wrong set of parameters is given) **even before** the`main` method is called?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way myself.

The most important thing here was that I need to use **runTask** instead of **fullRunInputTask**, but I need to wrap it in a **dynamic input task** in order to use the parser. And then I need to `evaluate` it to get the `InputTask` value for my `inputKey`.

So the actual task definition is:

```
clearDatabase := Def.inputTaskDyn {
  runTask(Compile, "my.code.ClearDatabaseTask", databaseTaskParser.parsed:_*)
}.evaluated
```

Now I also need to modify the parser to not return a tuple but a list or sequence, but still verify if the right number of params is passed. I did it like so:

```
val databaseTaskParser = sbt.Def.spaceDelimited("endpoint username password").map(_.toList).map {
  case args if List(1, 3).contains(args.length) => args.padTo(3, "")
  case _ =>
        sys.error("Supported arguments: \"endpoint\" or \"endpoint username password\"")
}
```

And this does the trick: `sbt clearDatabase` fails if given zero or two parameters and runs the `main` method in `my.code.ClearDatabaseTask` passing all the params if one or three are given, with no need for additional verification inside that method.